# Is Inverse Standard Normal Distribution $\Phi^{-1}(x)$ related to $erf^{-1}(x)$?

Tags: statistics

I am looking to use $normsinv$ to implement $inverf$ in a spreadsheet.

Cumulative Standard Normal Distribution, $\Phi$, is related to $\mathrm{erf}$:

$\Phi(x) = {1 \over 2}\left[1+\mathrm{erf}\left({x \over \sqrt 2}\right)\right]$

Is it correct (and can it be shown) that:

${1 \over \sqrt 2} \Phi^{-1}\left({1 \over 2}[1 + x]\right) =\mathrm{erf}^{-1}(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct, but you need to be careful about notation.

$\mathrm{erf}^{-1}(z):= \{x:\mathrm{erf}(x)=z\}$ Therefore, we know the value of $\mathrm{erf}$, but not the corresponding value of $x$. Lets use this fact to derive your answer.

$\Phi(x) = {1 \over 2}[1+\mathrm{erf}({x \over \sqrt 2})]\rightarrow \Phi(\sqrt{2}x) = {1 \over 2}[1+\mathrm{erf}({x})]$. Now, let $\mathrm{erf}(x)=z$. This simplifies our equation to:

$\Phi(\sqrt{2}x) = {1 \over 2}[1+z]\rightarrow \Phi^{-1}\left(\Phi(\sqrt{2}x)\right) = \Phi^{-1}\left({1 \over 2}[1+z]\right) \rightarrow x={1 \over \sqrt{2}}\Phi^{-1}\left({1 \over 2}[1+z]\right)=\mathrm{erf}^{-1}(z)\; \square$